# How do I find the last time a particular file was updated in perforce?

Tags: perforce

That is, for a given source file `foo.c`, how do I figure out the last time it was updated by anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
p4 filelog -s -m1 file
```

Explanation:

- `file` is the local path or depot path to the file in question
- `-m1` limits the output to the single most recent revision of the file
- `-s` specifies that you want a shortened output

Example:

```
p4 filelog -s -m1 foo.c
p4 filelog -s -m1 /path/on/disk/to/foo.c
p4 filelog -s -m1 //depot/path/to/foo.c
```